# Android UDP receive on phone via 3g or wifi

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, 3g

So, I'm testing my android game on my phone (HTC Legend) in debugging mode. I am trying to communicate with my custom JAVA server. I can receive UDP packages on my server, i can see them, but none of the responses from server ever reaches phone. 
I am using following code on my server to get client IP:port

```
datagramPackageIn.getAddress();
datagramPackageIn.getPort();
```

On the client side I use this code to see my address:

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In testing I can see that those 2 addresses are different. Maybe there is the problem?

I used standard UDP communication code (one that worked in emulator) in client:

```
run(){//simplified  version
while(true)
packageIN()
}
public packageIN(){
DatagramPacket packet= new DatagramPacket(inBuffer, inBuffer.length);
DatagramSocket socket= new DatagramSocket(receivingPort);

socket.receive();
}
```

So, any working solutions ( tested one with phone on 3g)?

P.S.
I know that HTC Legend has wifi problems, thats why I use 3G.....

Answer (score 0):

If the server shows a different IP address than the mobile device when you connect through 3G, you may be behind a NAT gateway. Some cell carriers do this. A sure sign of NAT is if the IP looks something like `10.x.x.x` or `192.168.x.x` or `172.y.x.x` (where `y`is between 16 and 31). I've also seen carriers assign NAT addresses of the form `1.x.x.x`.

With such a setup it depends on how the gateway handles UDP.

To rule out any errors caused by NAT, try accessing the server through WiFi and a LAN, not going through any networks that you don't control.

Comment: as i stated in my question, cant really use wifi because of known HTC wifi issues... but there must be a way around... its not like android never uses udp protocol regardless of NAT...